# Google Tag Manager - Count amount of pageviews

Tags: javascript, local-storage, google-tag-manager

I've made an event in Google Tag Manager, which triggers when a specific page is loaded.
The Event label  is the value of my user defined variable SearchCounter with type: Custom JavaScript.

[image]

In 'SearchCounter' I have the following JS:

```
  function(){
  var counter;
  if(localStorage.getItem("count_search") === null || localStorage.getItem("count_search") === 'undefined'){
    localStorage.setItem("count_search", "1");
    return localStorage.getItem("count_search");
  } 
  else{
    counter = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("count_search"));
    counter = counter + 1;

    localStorage.setItem("count_search", counter);
    return localStorage.getItem("count_search");
  }

return localStorage.getItem("count_search");
}
```

[image]

When I don't have the item in my local storage already, it still give's me 7 instead of 1. Then I'll press F5: count_search = 17, And again f5: 27. A CTRL-F5 gives me 37.
[image]

It should be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etcetera.

I hope someone can help me to implement a counter-alike function in Google Tag Manager, so I can send the amount of searches to GA, when a goal has been achieved. So, When someone clicks a specific button a would like to get the value of count_search, to send it to GA within an event.
Thanks very much.

Comment: How many dataLayer events do you have on every page?

Answer (score 0):

First of all this metric is given by google analytics by default so i don't see why ur trying to store it somewhere else. If you dont want the avg that google uses you can just store a custom dimension at 'Session' level with the sessionID and those in a custom report open Sessions by pageviews. [Here is info about it.](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/improve-data-collection-with-four-custom-dimensions/)

On the other hand, if you insist doing it your way i think even if this works it isn't the best approach you would get a much better result storing the counter in a custom dimension at 'Session' level. (It ll overwrite the value each time for a given session and you ll end up with the last one send)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is changing the name of the parameter saved in the localStorage. I don't know why, but `count_search` does not work. I tested your setup and encountered the same weird effect where the `count_search` item is summing up to astronomical numbers. Using a different name like `thisIsMyPageViewCounter` works just fine though! Probably `count_search` is accessed by another object in the document or window and you managed to get a value out of it by chance.

If you want to add the page view count to an event, I do not see any other way than creating both a Custom HTML Tag to set the counter and a Custom JS Variable to return the count.

This is the Custom HTML Script to be added to each page view:

```js
<script>
   (function() {
     if(localStorage.getItem("thisIsMyPageViewCounter") === null || localStorage.getItem("thisIsMyPageViewCounter") === 'undefined') {
       localStorage.setItem("thisIsMyPageViewCounter", 1);
  } else {
    var counter = 0;
    counter = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("thisIsMyPageViewCounter"));
    counter = counter + 1;

    localStorage.setItem("thisIsMyPageViewCounter", counter);
  }
})();
</script>
```

This is the Custom JS Variable to be added as a value to the event:

```js
function() {
    pageviewCounter = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("thisIsMyPageViewCounter")); 
    return pageviewCounter;
}
```

I hope this helps!